# Implement an one-way WCF method as asynchronous

Tags: wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone(Silverlight) application. Silverlight requires asynchronous calls.

The original method is `void SendImage(byte[] image)`. Now I made it asynchronous.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPhoneService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginSendImage(byte[] image, AsyncCallback cb, object obj);
    void EndSendImage(IAsyncResult r);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to implement the interface. Now I'm using the following code.

```
public class PhoneService : IPhoneService
{
    public event EventHandler<ImageReceivedEventArgs> ImageReceived;

    public IAsyncResult BeginSendImage(byte[] image, AsyncCallback cb, object obj)
    {
        if (ImageReceived != null) //BREAK POINT 1
            ImageReceived(this, new ImageReceivedEventArgs { ImageData = image });
        return new VoidAsyncResult(true, obj);
    }

    public void EndSendImage(IAsyncResult r)
    {
       //BREAK POINT 2
    }
}

internal class VoidAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{
    public VoidAsyncResult(bool isCompleted, object asyncState)
    {
        AsyncState = asyncState;
        IsCompleted = isCompleted;
    }

    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
    }

    public object AsyncState { get; private set; }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously { get { return false; } }
}
```

The client has the following code

```
ChannelFactory<IPhoneService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IPhoneService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://127.0.0.1:8000/phone"));
IPhoneService phone = factory.CreateChannel();
IAsyncResult s = phone.BeginSendImage(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, null, null);
phone.EndSendImage(s);
```

I set break point in BeginSendImage and EndSendImage. I find break point 1 is executed but break point 2 is not, and client hangs on phone.EndSendImage(s).

Did I write BeginSendImage and EndSendImage correctly? How do I fix the error?

Comment: You're not passing a reference to your callback method into the BeginSendImage call

Comment: I don't need to be called back so I pass null.